# How to put explanatory text inside textboxes in a form and focus cursor on fields?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, cursor-position

Basically two parts of the question.

1. How to put explanatory text inside textboxes in a form (like writing e-mail in the text area of a text box in a form) with styles (i.e. greyed out so that meant to suggest) like on facebook homepage.
2. How to put cursor focus on a particular form-field as soon as the page loads (like google sign-in or facebook sign-in)

Is there javascript involved in any of the above procedures? if yes, please specify

1. a non-javascript workaround and/or
2. the javascript code doing what is needed

Comment: I'm not sure what's going here, but don't downvote unless a) you're absolutely sure the answer is actually wrong. People need to read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/

Comment: ya one jQuery guy had to remove his post and still earn a badge perhaps. downvoting it wasn't required. ignorance is the best form of downvoting. vote up whatever you like, leave the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first trick is just a preset value. And when you click the field it has an onclick function that checks. Is the value "Write your email here". If so, clear the field. If not do nothing.

It then has an onblur function that checks, is the field empty. If so, print "Write your email here" in it.

The 2nd one is JavaScript as well.

[Here is](http://cznp.com/so/form_trick.php) an Example page with both these functions

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchBox()
    {
        elem = document.getElementById("search");

        if(elem.value == "Search...")
        {
            elem.value = "";
        }
    }

    function searchBoxBlur()
    {
        elem = document.getElementById("search");

        if(elem.value == "")
        {
            elem.value = "Search...";
        }
    }

    function init()
    {
        document.getElementById("other_box").focus();
        }
        window.onload = init;
    </script>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="other_box" id="other_box" />
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search..." onclick="searchBox()" onblur="searchBoxBlur()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great! thanks!
maybe they should remove the min 15 char limit on comments!
I wonder why they have it in the first place?

otherwise this comment could have had just "great thanks!" which would have done you, me and everybody else a lot more good (including my keyboard) ;-)

Comment: Lots of spaces after last character. Like I did in the Yes comment above. You don't see it but it's there.

Comment: neat!                                      .

Answer (score 1):

This will require javascript (via the jQuery framework). The following was quickly typed-up, and untested. May require some minor tinkering. If you have questions - ask :)

1. Auto-focus Desired Element
2. Change Element Text Color when out of focus
3. Show default text, when user-provided text isn't present

---

```
/* Run our work once the document is ready (loaded */
$(document).ready(function(){

  /* Set initial state of field */
  $("input.first-name").val("First Name").css("color", "#CCCCCC");

  /* Attach logic to the .focus() event of our input field */
  $("input.first-name").focus(function(){

    /* What to do when this field is focused */
    $(this).val("").css("color", "#333333");

  }).blur(function(){

    /* What to do when the field is blurred */
    if ($(this).val() == "") {

      /* Set value to 'First Name,' and set color to light gray */
      $(this).val("First Name").css("color", "#CCCCCC");

    }

  });

  /* Autofocus our field */
  $("input.first-name").focus();

});
```

Comment: is this jQuery? or javascript?

Comment: It's javascript, via the jQuery framework. jQuery basically makes javascript much easier to work with. It allows you to do more, quicker. And it keeps you from having to work out differences between the way IE, FF, and other browsers handle javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The first, quick and dirty:

```
<input name="foo" value="Default text OMG!" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Default text OMG!') this.value = ''"/>
```

Making that `onfocus` event a function in an external JavaScript file is recommend. That would yield:

External script:

```
function checkText(el,someText){ if(el.value == someText) el.value = ''}
```

Your input:

```
<input name="foo" value="Default text OMG!" onfocus="checkText(this,'Default text OMG!')"/>
```

The second: Give the input that you want "focused" an ID and do something like this:

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" value="Default text OMG!"/>
```

And in a script:

```
window.onload = function(){ document.getElementById('foo').focus() }
```

Comment: ya i agree with altcognito. :)
but Olafur's answewr turned out to be more comprehensive and nearer to what i wanted. still thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is no non-JavaScript way to do the first part of your question. As far as the second part is concerned, it can be easily done with JavaScript, but even without it, most modern browsers add focus to the first input field.

JavaScript code

1. Just set the value to the input field to your preset value:

   ```
   function focus_function()
   {
   if (this.value=="Enter email here") {
   this.value="";
   this.class="actualEmail";
   }
   }

   function blur_function()
   {
   if (this.value=="") {
   this.value="Enter email here";
   this.class="preset";
   }
   }
   ```

   You can have two CSS classes: `preset` and `actualEmail`, and specify different colors, etc.
2. Just have an onload function which puts focus on the required input field:

   ```
   window.onload = function() 
   {
   document.getElementById("email_field").focus();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are non-standard attributes you may consider: `placeholder` (works in safari i guess) and [`autofocus` (a part of HTML5 spec)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#autofocusing-a-form-control).

- [implement `placeholder` in Javascript](http://www.beyondstandards.com/archives/input-placeholders/)
- You can do the similar with `autofocus` (just fire `InputElement.focus()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
myField.focus();
```

That should place the cursor in myField when the page loads (if you place it at the end or in a `$(document).ready()` jQuery block).  I have seen some inconsistent behavior with this in different browsers, so your mileage may vary.

As far as setting the color of a text field's input, I would set it to have a default value and add a separate CSS class when the user clicks into it:

And your CSS would look like:

```
.grayedInputField {
    color: gray;
}
.activeInputField {
    color: black;
}
```

And when the user clicks into the field, have javascript add a class to the field to change the text color, like so (again, jQuery):

```
 $(".grayedInputField").focus(function(){$(this).addClass("activeInputField")});
```